# Setting input value when moving 'scroll control'

Tags: javascript, php

I've been working on a script that lets a user set a setting using HTML5' `<input type="range"`, I've got it to work and got it to show a value on my site, but the thing is that I want the user set setting to be posted as a form input `$_POST['gearsdrag']`.

For clearification I'm providing a JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqdesf70/

The input I want to be sent is 
`<input id="r" type="text" name="gearsdrag" value="6000" />`

But what the script set's is `<input id="r" type="text" name="gearsdrag" />6000</input>` and that's not being sent with `$_POST`.So is there a way to do this or maybe with get parameters or something.I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the function to this will insert the value into the input and from there you can post it is that what your after?

```
<script>function showValue(newValue)
{
    //changing the "innerHTML" to "value" is what inserts it into the text field

    document.getElementById("r").value = newValue;
    document.getElementById("rr").innerHTML = newValue;
}

</script>
Keisti pavarą prie: <span id="rr">0</span> / RPM
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="7800" value="0" step="100" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <input id="r" type="text" name="gearsdrag" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Nustatyti" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes that is what i was after, and if that was so easy I should stop coding :D Thanks!

Comment: @Kirilas you can also have the gearsdrag to a hidden input field and it will still allow you to post the value without the need for the 2nd  visible form element